# Posting form data to API

Tags: typescript, axios, next.js

I'm trying to finish a project in NextJs with TS and I made a form with 3 input fields (username, email, password) that should point towards my route /api/users.

I manage to get the information from my GET request but my POSTS simply do not work at all. I've tried multiple ways to get the req.body data or to pass it forward and I've done a lot of research but nothing seems to work.

Currently I have tried make this post like this:

```
        let user = {
      id: Date.now,
      // @ts-ignores ---
      username: document.getElementById('username').value,
      // @ts-ignores ---
      email: document.getElementById('email').value,
      // @ts-ignores ---
      password: document.getElementById('password').value
    } 

    return user
    console.log('localUserObject', userDb)
    api.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users', {user}).then(res => {console.log("POSTDATA", res.data)})
    console.log("/API/users", users)
```

And like this:

```
      async function onSubmit(data: any) {
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    let config = {
      method: 'post', 
      url: '/api/users',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      data: createUser(),
    }
    const response = await axios(config)
    console.log(response)
    // createUser()
  }
```

I'm really not sure why it isn't working and any help would be appreciated.
Here is my full form file (there's a lot of commented out code because I'm not sure what I should keep):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import data from '../component/data.json'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import axios from 'axios';
import { users } from '../data'

const api =axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:3000/api/users`
})
export default function Form(props:any) {
  const eng = props.eng
  const setReg = props.setReg
  const [userDb, setUserDb] = useState([])

  api.get('/').then(res => {
    console.log("API.GET DATA:", res.data)
    // setUserDb([res.data])
  })

  

  // type User = {
  //   username: string
  //   email: string
  //   password:string
  // }

  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

      
      const createUser = async () => {
        let res = await api.post('/', {
          id:"test", 
          username: document.getElementById('username').value,
          email: document.getElementById('email').value,
          password: document.getElementById('password').value
        })
        console.log(res)
        // let user = {
        //   id: Date.now,
        //   // @ts-ignores ---
        //   username: document.getElementById('username').value,
        //   // @ts-ignores ---
        //   email: document.getElementById('email').value,
        //   // @ts-ignores ---
        //   password: document.getElementById('password').value
        // } 

        // return user
        // console.log('localUserObject', userDb)
        // api.post('http://localhost:3000/api/users', {user}).then(res => {console.log("POSTDATA", res.data)})
        // console.log("/API/users", users)
      }
      
      async function onSubmit(data: any) {
        // console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        let config = {
          method: 'post', 
          url: '/api/users',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          data: createUser(),
        }
        const response = await axios(config)
        console.log(response)
        // createUser()
      }


  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>

    <main className={styles.mainForm}>
      <h1 className={styles.titleForm}>
      {eng ? data.eng.welcome : data.fr.welcome}
      </h1>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className={styles.form}>
        <div>
          <p className={styles.descriptionForm}>{eng ? data.eng.form : data.fr.form}</p>

          <label><b className={styles.description}>{eng ? data.eng.user : data.fr.user}</b></label>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            placeholder={eng ? data.eng.enterUser : data.fr.enterUser} 
            id="username" 
            {...register('username', {required: true})}
            />

          <label><b className={styles.description}>{eng ? data.eng.email : data.fr.email}</b></label>
          <input 
            type="email" 
            placeholder={eng ? data.eng.enterEmail : data.fr.enterEmail} 
            id="email" 
            {...register('email', {required: true})}
            />

          <label><b className={styles.description}>{eng ? data.eng.password : data.fr.password}</b></label>
          <input 
            type="password" 
            placeholder={eng ? data.eng.enterPassword : data.fr.enterPassword} 
            id="password" 
            {...register('password', {required: true})}
            />

          <button type="submit" onClick={(event) => {
            event.preventDefault()
            // @ts-ignores ---
              setReg(true)
          }} className={styles.registerbtn}><h1>{eng ? data.eng.save : data.fr.save}</h1></button>

        </div>
      </form>
    </main>
  </div>
  )
}
```

and here's my file users located at api/users

```
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

type Data = {
  id: string, 
  username: string, 
  email: string, 
  password: string
}

export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {
  res.status(200).json(   {
    id: "user1", 
    username: "señorJuan", 
    email: "C1@mail.com",
    password: "password"
  } )
}
```

I'm a very junior coder so the simplest way to solve this the best.
I tried preserving the users in an object/array inside my code but even when I added to the object it always ended up resetting to just hold the original value.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I recommend taking another look at the official docs on creating a form in React at https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html - it's generally bad form to rely on document.getElementById in a React app.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the code to create states that hold the values of the forms. While it works and I can log out the input correctly, the post doesn't seem to function at all. Any other resources you can refer me to to figure that last part out?